# how to run multiple fedora commands in python

Tags: python, linux, command-line, fedora

So I'm trying to have Python run multiple commands to install programs and enable SSH to setup my Linux computer. I would type all this in, but I'll be doing this to more devices, so I figured why not put in a Python script, but so far it's easier said than done. I did a boatload of research on this and I can't find anything like this.

So here's what I got so far.

```
--import subprocess
--SSH = "systemctl enable sshd"
--payload = "nmap" # it'll be one of a few I'll be installing

--subprocess.call(["sudo", "yum", "install", "-y", payload])
--subprocess.call(["sudo", SSH])
```

The first part of this works perfectly. It asks for my password it'll update and install nmap. But for some reason the command "systemctl enable sshd" seems to always throw it off. I know the command works because I can just type it out and it'll work just fine by itself, but for some reason it won't work through this script. I've used `subprocess.run` as well. What am I missing here?

Here's the error that I get:

```
--sudo: systemctl start sshd: command not found
```

Comment: for someone like this i would certainly recommend looking to writing a bash script instead

Answer (score 1):

What you want is Ansible.

Ansible uses SSH to connect to list of machines and perform configuration tasks. Tasks are described in YAML, which is readable and scale. You can have playbooks and ad hoc commands. For example ad hoc to install package will be

```
ansible -i inventory.file -m yum -a "name=payload state=present"
```

In a playbook will look like Install and enable openssh-server

```
---
- hosts: all                                      # Single or group of hosts from inventory file
  become: yes                                     # Become sudo
  tasks:                                          # List of tasks
  - name: Install ssh-server                      # Description free text
    yum:                                          # Module name
      name: openssh-server                        # Name of the package
      state: present                              # State " state: absent will uninstall the package"  
  - name: Start and enable service                # Description of the task free text
    service:                                      # Service
      name: sshd                                  # Name of the service
      state: started                              # Started or Stopped
      enabled: yes                                # Start the service on boot
                     
  - name: Edit config file sshd_config            # Description of the task
    lineinfile:                                   # Name of the module
      path: /etc/sshd/sshd_config                 # Which file to edit
      regex: ^(# *)?PasswordAuthentication        # Which line to edit
      line: PasswordAuthentication no             # Whit what to change it
```

Ansible have great documentation https://docs.ansible.com/ in a few days you will be up to speed.

Best regards.

Comment: Awesome thank you I'll look into it and let you know what I find!